# Calculate difference between date column entries and date minimum Pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I feel like this is a stupid question, but I cannot seem to figure it out, so here goes. I have a PySpark data frame and one of the columns consists of dates. I want to compute the difference between each `date` in this column and the minimum `date` in the column, for the purpose of filtering to the past `numberDays`. I've tried several possibilities but nothing seems to work. Here is my most recent attempt:

```
df = df.filter(
        F.datediff(
            F.col("collection_date"),
            F.lit(F.min(F.col("collection_date")))
        ) >= numberDays
    )
```

But I've also tried:

```
df_new = df.withColumn("days", df.select("collection_date") - df.select("collection_date").min())
```

and

```
df_new = df.withColumn("days", df.select("collection_date") - df.select(F.min("collection_date")))
```

There's probably a few others, but I can't seem to get this to work, although I'm sure there's an incredibly simple answer.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that I don't really care for, but it appears to work.

```
df = df.filter(
        F.datediff(
            F.col("collection_date"),
            F.lit(df.agg(F.min(df["collection_date"])).collect()[0][0])
        ) >= numberDays
    )
```

I'm don't think it's particularly good practice to put a `collect()` operation in the middle of the code, but this works. If anyone has a more "Sparky" solution, please let me know.

**EDIT 3/21/2022**:
Here is a more Spark-y way of doing this:

```
df = (
        df
        .sort(F.col("collection_date").asc())
        .filter(
            F.datediff(
                F.col("collection_date"),
                F.lit(df.select(F.min("collection_date")).first()["min(collection_date)"])
            ) >= numberDays
        )
    )
```